# Is it OK to use more than one OR in a sentence?

Tags: grammar

Is it OK to use more than one OR in a sentence?
Like this

```
I should eat mango or bananas or pineapple?
```

Comment: Better to say *I should eat mango, bananas or pineapple*.

Answer (score 1):

Without disagreeing with WS2, I would say it is quite common in conversation. Either for emphasis or to add an item that has been forgotten, e.g

John, you should eat mango or bananas - or pineapple. (an afterthought)

John, you should eat mango OR bananas OR pineapple. (emphasis)